# How to get boundaries of a current map in R?

Tags: r, google-maps, maps

Dealing with R, plotting some maps.

```
map <- get_map(location='ukraine', zoom=5, maptype="terrain", source='google', color='color')
```

Map from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=ukraine&zoom=5&size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=terrain&language=en-EN&sensor=false

Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=ukraine&sensor=false

How to get the boundaries of the received map?
e.g. minimum long - maximum long.... 
min lat - max lat...

Comment: The `str()` function is your BFF and would have eventually led you to using `attributes(map)$bb`. Note that `map` is a terrible choice for a variable name that will some day come back to haunt you.

Comment: Thank's a lot for your answer & advice!